# App crashes on Requesting Product Data via store kit for IAP on some devices

Tags: ios, crash, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am working on a unity project where I have integrated IAP via StoreKit. When I request product data, my app crashes. This is just happening on some device. On others, it works fine.

My app crashes with
`BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: itunesstored apsd`

I get an exception after
UnitySendMessage at WebScripting.cpp  in thread [storekitmanager paymentqueue: update transactions:]

This is happening even on the first time after installing the app and requesting product data.

Can somebody please help me with the issue.

Comment: This happened on only a certin device. You need to reset hour ipad. Everything will be okay. It ia juat that sometimes,ypur purchase gets stuck. And you have to factory reset your device.

Comment: Looks like its a problem that isn't present when the game is in "production" - we used MobiShop from the assetstore (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/63636) its a solution which also allows you to test it in Unity so that you know that the problem is not becaurse you trigger "buy" two times and wait for the purchase to finish,

Comment: Any update or solution to this? I've encountered it several times and never have been clear on why or how.